# Geb/Selenium - Other element would receive the click

Tags: jquery, html, selenium, geb

I'm using a mixture of Geb and Selenium to do front end testing for our web portal. Our former developers implemented an overlay div to block any access to page when waiting for content. Thus, I often have to wait for this div to not being visible any longer before I can click on an element of interest.

I applied a fluent wait to check for overlay div not visible but sometimes the click goes to this overlay div anyway. That's really strange: The overlay is not visible resp. not attached to the DOM tree but the click goes to it.

How can this happen?
What can I do to work around this issue?

Comment: my guess is that its not waiting for it to fade out (disappear).  check the timeout on that wait, and increase if necessary?

Comment: Ya, I ran into same situation and came up with a workaround of doing while loop for the element to return `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: Here comes my fluent wait:

Comment: def timeout = 60
        boolean isNotBusy = new FluentWait(driver)
            .withMessage("Busy overlay still visible after $timeout seconds.")
            .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .withTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException.class)
            .ignoring(UnhandledAlertException.class)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(by) as Function);

Comment: Means, I'm waiting for 60 seconds. But my fluent wait is ignoring the NoSuchElementException

Comment: @Saifur: Could you please provide a code snippet as a possible solution?

Comment: try `while (Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("Selector for overlay")).Count > 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
            }` Note: this is C#.

Comment: @Saifur: Thanks! I've changed my fluent wait a bit to not ignore the NoSuchElementException any longer. Now, I'm waiting for this exception to be sure that overlay has vanished from DOM tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the fluent wait:

```
protected final boolean waitForPageNotBusy(By by = By.className("busyOverlay")) {
    log.debug("Waiting for page not busy...")
    def timeout = 120
    boolean isNotBusy = new FluentWait(driver)
        .withMessage("Busy overlay still visible after $timeout seconds.")
        .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .withTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .ignoring(org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException.class)
        .ignoring(UnhandledAlertException.class)
        .until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(by) as Function);
    isNotBusy
}
```

by a loop suggested by Saifur:

```
protected final boolean waitForPageNotBusy() {
    By by = By.className("busyOverlay")
    log.debug("Waiting for element to disappear: {}", by.toString())
    try {
        while (driver.findElements(by).size() > 0) {
            log.debug("Element still visible: {}", by.toString())
            sleep(1000)
        }
    } catch (NoSuchElementException nse) {
        log.debug(nse.message)
        return true
    }
}
```

could solve my problem.